# How do I indent entire file by n spaces in VIM?

Tags: vim

I want to indent an entire text file with n spaces in VIM.

My current method is:

1. Go to the beginning of the file
2. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
3. Press the down key <kbd>↓</kbd> or the <kbd>j</kbd> key to select the lines to indent
4. Type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
5. Type the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> key n times
6. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Is there a way to accomplish this without using visual mode and having to manually go through the entire file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use a Global Substitution

Assuming you want to indent four spaces, you can do this:

```
:%s/^/    /
```

This will effectively insert four spaces at the start of each line. Adjust the number of spaces on the right-hand side of the substitution expression to suit your indentation needs.

### Using Visual Mode

Alternatively, you can go into normal mode and then:

1. <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>
2. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
3. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
4. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>

to indent the entire file by the value of *shiftwidth*.

Answer (score 5):

how about:

```
:%s/^/(you count n spaces here)/
```

Answer (score 3):

A `:normal` variant that adds two spaces at the beginning of every line:

```
:%norm 0i<space><space><CR>
```

Another `:normal` variant that adds two spaces before the first printable character of every line:

```
:%norm I<space><space><CR>
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to place the number of spaces you want inserted to be placed in front of the `i` command. (`:%norm 02i<space><CR>`)

Comment: @FDinoff, I agree but I went with a more intuitive approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can indent a set of lines like this:

```
:1,44>
```

If you press `ctrl-g`, it will give you the last line of the file.

Comment: `:1,$>` will cover the entire file.

Comment: @MichaelKristofik `:%>` will do. however this indent the file, not by `n` spaces. e.g. I want to "indent" the entire file by 7 spaces (n=7), does this (`>`) work?

Comment: `:set sw=4` (for any value) sets the number of spaces by which `>` and `<` will indent. it also sets the value by which a normal `>>` or `<<` will indent/unindent... normally, you would set this the same as the tab stops (`:set ts=4`) as well, and also `:set expand`...

Comment: @CorleyBrigman it depends on the `tab` options too. here OP wants the `n` **spaces**.  with `>` operation, `<tab>` may be inserted.

Comment: this is true... i mistyped it, the option you want is `:set expandtab`, which will replace all tabs with spaces, including ones it would have put in itself.